# Delete Cookie Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, cookies

I'm passing some information at login inside a cookie, information which I need to remove at logout. For passing & deleting the cookie, I'm using HttpServletResponse. The cookie is visible in the client, but not deleted.
Adding the cookie:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setSecure(false);
cookie.setMaxAge(age);
cookie.setPath("/"); 
cookie.setDomain("localhost");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Remove:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, null);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setSecure(false);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setDomain("localhost");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

The name passed is the same, I'm using a constant variable for both, so this is not the issue. I read a lot of questions, but all of them were solved with setMaxAge to 0, which in my case is set correctly. I don't know what to do.

Comment: cookies are client-based data, therefore you cannot destroy them (or at least it would be useless since the user can modify it). what you can do is checking the cookie data, which may contain a string authenticating the user. when user logs out, invalidate data checking so that it will act the same as if the cookie was invalid

Comment: @R.LM actually, the server can tell the browser that he needs to delete the cookie. I'm guessing that's what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: from what I saw, the thing here is to override cookie data, but still, cookie data may never be trusted.

Comment: @MatheusCirillo the client may opt to not delete the cookie. It is best practice to void the cookie, i.e. set its value to, e.g., an empty string.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set it to a default value, like null or empty string, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: What is your client? A browser will invalidate the cache as soon as its max-age is reached. Unless you are using Internet Explorer which doesn't work well with max-age. you will have to close the browser.

Comment: I have a max age of seven days initially, but I want to override it, so I set it to be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution and I want to post it here to help other developers in need.

The problem was not with my backend, the cookie was set correct and also deleted as specified in documentation. But the fact was that the cookie was set from an endpoint that does not require authentication and I was trying to delete it from an endpoint which requires authentication.

As you can deduce, the problem was with my front-end and cors requests. I had to add an interceptor where for every request I added {withCredentials: true}, which enabled to send & accept cookies from the server.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
req = req.clone({
  withCredentials: true
});
return next.handle(req);
}
```

Thanks!